# jquery menu slide up/down - keeping sub-menus open when not mouse moves away?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to create horizontal menu which go downside on mouse on the main menu and downside on mouse out.

The problem is that I want the div under the menu to still appear if mouse moved from one menu item to another one which also have submenu.

here is the HTML

```
 <div class="menu_it">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="i1"><a href="#">
                          program 1
                            </a>
                            <div class="subMenuWrapper">
                                <ul class="subMenu">
                                    <li> <a href="#"> sub program 1</a></li>
                                      <li> <a href="#"> sub program 1</a></li>
                                            <li> <a href="#"> sub program 1</a></li>

                                </ul> 
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li id="i2"> 
                            <a href="#"> program 2</a>

                            <div class="subMenuWrapper">
                                <ul class="subMenu">
                                       <li> <a href="#"> sub program 2</a></li>
                                     <li> <a href="#"> sub program 2</a></li>
                                     <li> <a href="#"> sub program 2</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li id="i3" ><a href="#"> sub program 3</a>

                        </li>

 </ul>
</div>
 <div class="noti"><span class="text">
 This is a notification bar   This is a notification bar   This is a notification bar   This is a notification bar   This is a notification bar   This is a notification bar   This is a notification bar 
    </span>
</div>
```

and here is the js

```
$('.menu_it > ul li:has(> div ul)').on('mouseenter',function(e) {
    console.log('in');


                  $(this).find('div').slideDown('fast');
                 $('.noti').animate({'margin-top':'41'} ); 


            })
            .on('mouseleave',function(e) {
            console.log('out');

               $(this).find('div').slideUp('fast');
              $('.noti').animate({'margin-top':'0'} );  


            });
```

Here's the [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDc4Y/) I am working on, how can I make div with class noti still open if mouse move from li with id 1 ti li with id2

If there is a better way for smooth sliding up and down for the submeu I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```
$('.menu_it > ul li:has(> div ul)').on('mouseenter', function (e) {

    $(this).find('div').slideDown('fast');
    $('.noti').animate({
        'margin-top': '41'
    });
})
    .on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    $(this).find('div').slideUp('fast');
    if ($('.menu_it > ul li:hover div ul').length != 1) 
        $('.noti').animate({
            'margin-top': '0'
        });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDc4Y/1/)**

Comment: it still have problem when I mouse is over li in submenu, it slides the .noti up!

Comment: What is the problem now..?

Comment: Actually it is not a problem it's logical, the .noti slides up when the mouse is over it (not over submeu li). I doubt if this is logically correct for menus or not?